# Magento under XAMPP very slow on windows

Tags: magento2, xampp

Config 8gb ram,250gb sdd , xamp , magento 2.3
Still magento runs slow on windows 10.
i can see disk usage stays on 0% through out magento surfing.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: not sure on Win10 but in macOS MAMP enabling XDebug can slow down a lot apache. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8677388/8243229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give the official answer Magento would give you.

Magento isn't supported on windows so your experience will be less than ideal if it works at all. If you would like to develop magento you should do so on a supported linux distrabution.

A personal suugestion would be to use a container system/virtual machine or a full distro via a dual boot. Do not expect production/server proformance unless you are providing the resources on a supported operating system.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you Please suggest any virtual machine except VMware ?

Comment: Oracle Virtualbox is my go to. I just use a debian vm, but pick your prefered flavour of linux. You can also look at container systems like vagrant. It's less than full performance but it's not awful.

Comment: using this https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-in-virtualbox/ 
Will magento runs faster/better on my system config
240gb SSD 8gb Ram Celeron processor ?

Comment: The speed will be similar to slightly worse, but you won't have to deal with hacking magento core or other problems given to you by windows. As long as you setup magento, permissions and user groups correctly, you should have an easier time. Don't expect miracles with your hardware. You will have to become familiar with linux as well going this route.

Comment: I was just concerned about magento speed, may be it will run faster on linux with same configuration then windows. What you think ?

Comment: It can be, depending on what you use and what you configure. If you use encryption on the hdd/ssd drive it won't be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110802/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-mark-rees).

Answer (score 0):

use this command to change mode to developer :

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

also set your full page cache to 1 in yout app/etc/env.php:

```
'full_page' => 1  ,
```

it will fasten your launch